# Google Tag manager: get the amount of time (minutes/seconds) it takes to complete progress

Tags: time, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an issue with tracking the completion of a progress within a web application. I want to track the amount of time it take for a user to finish a process (let's say he fills in an form, get's a confirmation and accepts the term/confirmation).
The process takes place in three different pages.

These are the three pseudo pages:

```
Page 1: Form
Page 2: Confirmation
Virtual pageview: Registration completed
```

The Virtual pageview is being made when the user has pressed the submit button and there are no errors on the screen.

What I would like to know now is:

- How to track the amount of time (seconds/minutes) it took the user to complete the registration? (in GTM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom HTML in GTM just start a timer when the user is on the first page and start filling the form on page unload save the time in a cookie.
At the last page when the registration is complete send an event with the cookie value containing the total time taken by the user in event value. Later you can analyze the average time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know another solution without cookies? We had some issues with cookies where the value of the cookie was undefined/not found before (i think because some of our users use some ancient version of internet explorer).

Comment: An alternative might be to store three different custom metrics (one per step) and then use a calculated metric to get the total in GA. While this is a rather roundabout way it gives you more information (e.g. you can see how long the individual steps took). Caveat is that you need to create a custom report, because custom metrics do not show in the standard reports.

Comment: Then Eike's solution is good and if you don't want to use your custom metric and want to see this in the standard report then you can use "Events". Create an event and fire in all 3 pages with different labels as step1, step2 or step 3 with event value the total time taken by the user.

Comment: @EikePierstorff  Can you add your comment as an answer. So I can accept this as an answer.